# Cairo dock, white border lines on all icons

Tags: unity, icons, cairo-dock

I have ubuntu 13.10 (I think, the latest one) and even though I love Unity I kind of did not like the left bar.

So I installed cairo dock which is great, BUT at random times the whole dock gets white border lines around every icon. Quitting cairo and restarting it, does not help, the only thing that helps is computer reboot.

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: http://glx-dock.org/bg_forumlist.php

Comment: Of course I can ask on a bunch of different forums, but I thought that is what the purpose of "Ask Ubuntu" is ....

Comment: Terminal thank Your time and  for this answer but this does not cut it ..I do not want to re-install cairo as a work around, I am trying to find the problem and fix it..  Because re-installing it everytime something like that happens is not really a way out of the situation..

Comment: Not meaning to insult, just best to go straight to the source. That is official forum & most likely to be populated by experts in your problem. It's not really a Ubuntu question, but maybe that's not for me to say.

Answer (score 0):

Completely remove Cairo dock, just press Ctrl+Alt+T on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
  sudo apt-get purge cairo-dock cairo-dock-plug-ins && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

And to install:

```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cairo-dock-team/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install cairo-dock cairo-dock-plug-ins
```